# How to make slideshow pause on mouse over and add tabs with progress of slide and fix timeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

Hi I am trying to fix my content slideshow. I am trying to add the ability of tabs with simple progress bars above like vodafone.co.uk and also add play/pause ability. I am also trying to figure out how to fix the issue when I clear the setInterval() when clicking next or prev button that the slider doesn't play.

Anyway ill leave my code below and hopefully someone could kindly help me, this is my first post on this community! Looking forward to getting involved with it!

```
<div id="slider">
  <a onclick="return false" class="control_next">></a>
  <a onclick="return false" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 4000);

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    clearInterval(timer);
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    clearInterval(timer);
    });

    return timer;

});    
</script>
```

You can also find our jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3uwptxu7/)

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You need a `play` control to auto play the slider again.

Comment: @Ishettyl How would i do this?

Comment: Is that what you're after? http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Comment: If you want it to continue playing, why are you clearing the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider code could be optimised for minimal code and better performance. What I understood from your questions is that you'd like to auto play the carousel on load, click on prev/next buttons stops auto play, and an option to start auto play again via a play button. That's what I did here along with a stop option. Feel free to edit and adapt the code accordingly.

The sections I've added:

```
$('a.control_play').click(function () {
    $('a.control_play').hide();
    $('a.control_pause').show();
    moveRight();
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 4000);
});

$('a.control_pause').click(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    $('a.control_play').show();
    $('a.control_pause').hide()
});
```

I have also added those 2 buttons in your HTML and modified prev/next navigation click functions. Take a good look. Here is [**a link to your complete code**](https://jsfiddle.net/3uwptxu7/3/) with my additons.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do but I have been playing around with the code and can't seem to get a progress bar at the bottom of the current slide to show.. Ughhh so annoying lol

Comment: What kind of progress bar?